# Applying for a Schengen visa as a tourist in Romania?

Tags: visas, italy, romania

I am a US permanent resident applying for a short-stay visa to Romania where I intend to stay for a month. I also wish to travel to Italy for a week in the third week of that month, but the Italian Embassy has told me that I would need to have the Romanian visa first. The concern is that by the time the Romanian visa is ready, I may not have time to complete the process for the Italian tourist visa.

My question is whether I can make my application at the Italian Embassy in Romania being there on a non-resident visa?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even though Romania is a part of the EU, it is not a part of the Schengen region for which I need to obtain a seperate visa.

Comment: You don't mention your citizenship. Please do, it is relevant to the question. Also, it's worth noting that if you have a currently valid, multi-entry Schengen Visa, then you don't need a seperate Romanian visa.

Comment: @CMaster If the OP needs a Schengen visa, and he obviously does, since Romania requires a short-stay visa from the same citizens as the countries in the Schengen area, the exact citizenship is not important.

Comment: @rayven1lk Was the processing of the Romanian visa delayed due to some reason outside of your control, or did you apply for the Romanian visa so late, that you therefore don't have time to apply for an Italian visa at your place of residence?

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo, getting the Romanian visa wasn't the easiest process as my citizenship status required me to receive a pre-approved invitation from their interior ministry. I think I have applied for my visa at a reasonable time frame, which is nearly 2 months before the flight. However I am not sure how long it will take them to get things done on their end. Right now their consulate is at the stage of validating my documents and hasn't provided me an appointment time as of yet.

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo and at this point, it is close to 6 weeks to my departure flight

Comment: @rayven1lk If there are 6 weeks to your flight, you still have plenty of time to get the Romanian visa and later apply for the Schengen visa from the Italian consulate.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo that may depend on where the applicant lives.  For example, someone living in Denver would have to travel to Chicago, 1000 miles (1600 km) away.  This is a similar distance to that between Milan and Bucharest.

Comment: @phoog, distance is not really an issue. It is the time. I actually went on the website to book an appointment at the Italian consulate that serves my state and the earliest slot I could get was dec 17th. However, this means I will have less than 2 weeks to get that visa. And that's assuming I will have my Romanian visa at that point of time. I sent my file for validation on the 4th of Nov and it's the 22nd of Nov and still nothing. (18 days)

Answer (score 2):

The Italian consulate in Bucharest have an astonishingly [awful website](http://www.ambbucarest.esteri.it/Ambasciata_Bucarest/Menu/Informazioni_e_servizi/Visti/) which fails to list any useful information. However their consulate in the US has a good website, which lists the following question [in their FAQ](http://www.consnewyork.esteri.it/consolato_newyork/en/i_servizi/per_chi_si_reca_in_italia/faqs.html):

> *My US visa is expired as well as my I-94 and I cannot renew it in the US. Can I apply for a Schengen visa?*
>
> No, you cannot. **We can process visa request only from legal residents of the US.**

I presume their Romanian office has a similar policy, so you wouldn't be able to apply there.

Comment: There ain't no way I'm awarding you my bounty. *pouting pouting pouting*

Comment: @JoErNanO looks like you had no choice, hehe

Comment: It's ok I'll go answering one of your questions now. :)